# Selected row changes when scrolling UITableView

Tags: objective-c

currently my situation is my fist row is checked by default. but when i want to uncheck it, it need user to click twice to uncheck it. may i know where i done wrongly?

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Report_SelectGroupTableViewCell";
   Report_SelectGroupTableViewCell *cell = (Report_SelectGroupTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Report_SelectGroupTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.indexPath = indexPath;
        cell.delegate = self;

    }
   // [myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:0 animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    //[self tableView:myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:0];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:NO];


    NSString *groupID = [[groupArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"group_id"];

    if ([groupID isEqualToString:selectedGroup]){

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [groupArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        BOOL isSelected = [[dict objectForKey:@"isSelected"] boolValue];
        if (!isSelected) {
            isSelected = !isSelected;
            [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected] forKey:@"isSelected"];
        }
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }

    cell.groupName.text = [[groupArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"group_name"];

    NSMutableDictionary *typeDict = [groupArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.tickButton.selected = [[typeDict objectForKey:@"isSelected"] boolValue];


    if (cell.tickButton.selected) {
        [cell.tickButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
        if([cell.groupName.text isEqual:@"All Users"])
        {
            [cell.tickButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_Icon_empty.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }

    }
    else{
        [cell.tickButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    }

    if([cell.groupName.text isEqual:@"All Users"])
    {

        [cell.tickButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.tickButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
        [typeDict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"isSelected"];


    }
      return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Report_SelectGroupTableViewCell *cell = (Report_SelectGroupTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [groupArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    BOOL isSelected = [[dict objectForKey:@"isSelected"] boolValue];
    isSelected = !isSelected;
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected] forKey:@"isSelected"];



    if (cell.tickButton.isSelected == YES)
    {
        [cell.tickButton setSelected:NO];
        [cell.tickButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        if([cell.groupName.text isEqual:@"All Users"])
        {
            [cell.tickButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_Icon_empty.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

    }
    else if (cell.tickButton.isSelected == NO)
    {
        [cell.tickButton setSelected:YES];
        [cell.tickButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove

```
[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:0 animated:YES scrollPosition:
 UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

and use this to select the first row (this should be called once outside this method or you want to set this row selected everytime each cell is render)

```
[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

And I don't know why you called this in this method

```
[myTableView.delegate tableView:myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:0];
```

but if you want to call it you should change to this too

```
[myTableView.delegate tableView:myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

ps. You should set the cell's selectionStyle correctly to see the cell is selected.

Update::
Try to replace all codes in the method with this

```
Report_SelectGroupTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Report_SelectGroupTableViewCell"];
if (!cell){
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Report_SelectGroupTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
return cell;
```

Please tell me if the first row is not selected and highlighted.

Comment: i add in [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] but it still will overwrite it

Comment: Please try in the updated answer and tell me the result.

Comment: the row was highlighted and didn't change row after scrolling but how to use button image to replace it?

Comment: You not use the cell's selection style to display that the cell is selected right? You set [cell.tickButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor]; for the selected row?

If you work in that way, I think you should understand how UITableViewCell and dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: work. And you need to handle you cell properties carefully because the cell object may be used for display for the other row.

Comment: if([cell.groupName.text isEqual:@"All Users"])
    {
        
        [cell.tickButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.tickButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
        
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.tickButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.tickButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];

    }
right now i had this code on cellforrow

Comment: Did it work correctly for you now? If not, you should explain more information about your work flow for me because this is your own custom cell.

Comment: if([cell.groupName.text isEqual:@"All Users"])
    {
        if(test==1)
        {
            [cell.tickButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.tickButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
            
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.tickButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.tickButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
           
        }
    }

Comment: Please edit in your post if you want to post code. It will be easier to read than in comment ^^.

Comment: i have done edit the post. Please help me take a look on it. Thanks @Suttikeat Witchayakul

Comment: Now your problem is not about the API but it was your app. work flow. Because you choose to manage the selected cell by your self instead of using the UITableView's functions. I can't help you for more.

Comment: But if you want to handle it by yourself you should care about the cell's properties because each cell maybe used for display for more than one row that is the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier concept. Good luck.